# Order Numerically by more than single digits

Tags: javascript, sorting

How should this code be altered to correctly order / sort numerically and alphabetically? This solution doesn't work for more than 100 items.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/5329/

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

The only workable solution I can implement so far is to give all items a three-digit number, e.g. 001, but this not pretty. globalhungerindex.org/countries.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/5329/

Comment: Note this alteration fixes some bugs in Chrome (but not the sorting problem)

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
      
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function() {
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ($(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text() ? 1 : -1);
  });
  $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function() {
  var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ($(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text() ? 1 : -1);
  });
  $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});

    });

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments

Comment: [`return … > …` is not a valid comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Comment: If we add more than a hundred items to the list, none of these solutions works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parseFloat()` function to parse the numerical value.

```
$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text()) > parseFloat($(b).find("h2").text());
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text` of an Element is always a String. To convert it to a number, you will need to cast it to a `Number`.

```
Number("20") = 20
```

```js
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return Number($(a).find("h2").text()) > Number($(b).find("h2").text());
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.box {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.box h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.box h2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <button id="alphBnt">Alphabetical</button>
    <button id="numBnt">Numerical</button>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="box">
        <h1>B<h1>
        <h2>10.35</h2>  
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <h1>A<h1>
        <h2>119</h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <h1>D<h1>
        <h2>2</h2>  
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <h1>C<h1>
        <h2>20</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @RorySturdy Did you try the code snippet? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @RorySturdy Could you please put your code in a JSFiddle for me?

Comment: Sure, here is your code, not working with more than 100 items: http://jsfiddle.net/pfxo07s9/11/

Comment: Here is my code, working, but I have to type every number as three digits which is not pretty: http://jsfiddle.net/u9mLatdn/1/

Comment: Note: I have included one blank entry, and fourteen non-numbered entries which will be required. These appear first in the numerical order, which is correct.